# Why does this very basic CLion project of C++ run in my lab comptuer but errors "undefined reference to" in mine?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion

I'm new in Object Oriented Programming in C++. This is my project named "graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu" and here is folder hierarchy

graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu/src/CMakeLists.txt

graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu/src/main.cpp

graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu/src/Array/Element.h

graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu/src/Array/Element.cpp

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu main.cpp
Array/Element.cpp
Array/Element.h
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array/Element.h"

using namespace array;
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout<<"test";
    Element e = Element();
    return 0;
}
```

Element.cpp

```
#include "Element.h"

namespace array {

    Element::Element(int data) {
        this->data = data;
    }

    int Element::getData() {
        return data;
    }

    Element::Element() {

    }

}
```

Element.h

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURES_CPP_ELEMENT_H
#define DATASTRUCTURES_CPP_ELEMENT_H

namespace array {

    class Element {
    private:
        int data;
    public:
        Element();

        explicit Element(int data);

        int getData();
    };

}
#endif //DATASTRUCTURES_CPP_ELEMENT_H
```

When I run my main.cpp, this error shows up:

```
g++.exe C:\Users\Halil\CLionProjects\graph-puzzle-game-halil-nebioglu\src\main.cpp -o main
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Halil\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9E8RP8.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `array::Element::Element()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Array folder is provided from another git project called DataStructures-CPP. I produced this very simple project on the laboratory computer and committed it to git. It worked fine. However, when I pulled it from my own computer, it started giving the following error. There were a lot of other folders and files but I just reduced every other thing to detect the problem. What can it be?

It just had to print "test", and does this when I remove `Element e = Element();`. However, if I use this, it says "Building main.cpp: failed..."

[image: Screenshot of the CLion]

Solution

Starting from @Tsyvarev's comment, I solved the problem. It happens because my configuration is a "C/C++ File", not a "CMakeApplication". I edited my configuration as such and it is working now.

[image: My Configurations]

Target is the project name, and executable is the "add_executable..." part of CMakeLists.txt

Comment: The CMakefiles.txt is correct but you've done something to ignore it.  The command-line you quoted is treating `main.cpp` as the sole source file and not compiling or linking Element.cpp

Comment: Note that you cannot run `main.cpp`.  It is not executable, nor is it complete source for an executable. It's unclear how you are eliciting the behavior you describe, but a misunderstanding on this point might be contributing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry if I misunderstood some terminology here. It has an int main function, I configured such that src\main.cpp is my source file and Toolchain is MinGW. Then I clicked "Run main.cpp". I was talking about this as running.

Comment: Get CLion to actually use your `CMakeLists.txt`. It's correct and should work.

Comment: @HalilNebioğlu, I know nothing about CLion or what a button in it labeled "Run main.cpp" would do.  But I do find such a label very suspicious, because none of the more likely things I imagine a button labelled in that way might do are in fact correct things for your particular project.  And indeed, what that button *actually* seems to be trying to do for you is incorrect.

Comment: ***Then I clicked "Run main.cpp". I was talking about this as running.*** VSCode has an addon that is called code-runner which uses similar terminology. This is unfortunate because in c++ you don't run source files. You instead compile and link then run the executable produced.

Comment: @drescherjm I already have CLion. I added a screenshot.

Comment: @HalilNebioğlu: You need tell CLion that you have CMake project, not a standalone `main.cpp` file. See e.g. [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-new-project-from-scratch.html#open-prj).